# mysql inserting first field into entire table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Okay... I am at a loss here. Turning here for help.

I am trying to insert a csv file full of user information into the database. I am checking to see if the UserID exists first, then if not, using a simple query statement to insert the data for each user.

The problem is, instead of inserting all the user data into one row, it's inserting just the first name into every field in the row.

**FirstName**
**LastName**
**Address**

George George George

I didn't assign an auto-incrementing key, because I already have a USERID I would like to use as a reference. Shouldn't this code be doing what I want?

```
    $stmt2 = $con->query("INSERT INTO Persons
                (First_Name, Middle_Initial, Last_Name, Address, Address2, City, State, Zip_Code,Daytime_Phone,Nighttime_Phone,Customer_ID)
                VALUES ('$FirstName','$MiddleInitial','$LastName','$Address','$Address2','$City','$State','$Zip','$DayPhone','$NightPhone','$CustomerID')");
```

This is how I am assigning php variables

```
    if (($handle = fopen("data/" . $File, "r")) !== FALSE) {
// File is available
// retrieve one data line at a time
$row = 1;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    if ($row == 1) {
        // These are the column names
        $FormattedFields = str_replace(' ', "", $data);
        preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/', '', $FormattedFields);
        foreach ($FormattedFields as $Key => $UpperField) {
            $LowerField = strtolower($UpperField);
            $NewFields[$Key] = $LowerField;
        }

        $FNL = array_search('firstname', $NewFields);
        $LNL = array_search('lastname', $NewFields);
        $MIL = array_search('middleinitial', $NewFields);
        $AL = array_search('middleinitial', $NewFields);
        $A2L = array_search('middleinitial', $NewFields);
        $CL = array_search('middleinitial', $NewFields);
        $SL = array_search('middleinitial', $NewFields);
        $ZL = array_search('middleinitial', $NewFields);
        $DPL = array_search('middleinitial', $NewFields);
        $NPL = array_search('middleinitial', $NewFields);
        $CIDL = array_search('middleinitial', $NewFields);
    } else {
        $FirstName = $data[$FNL];
        $MiddleInitial = $data[$MIL];
        $LastName = $data[$LNL];
        $Address = $data[$AL];
        $Address2 = $data[$A2L];
        $City = $data[$CL];
        $State = $data[$SL];
        $Zip = $data[$ZL];
        $DayPhone = $data[$DPL];
        $NightPhone = $data[$NPL];
        $CustomerID = $data[$CIDL];
```

Comment: Can you show code on how you are assigning values for your php variables?

Comment: Eeeh.... This is a hack job... Let me try.

Comment: You are clearly setting `$FirstName`, `$LastName`, etc. to the same value somehow.

Comment: Also, based on what you have posted so far, you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: I'm not worried about security, I understand this is susceptible to injection, but thanks for the tip. This is a local script only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `array_search('middleinitial', $NewFields)` to find *every* column from `middleinitial` onwards, so you are going to get the same value in all of those columns.

Also, as I said in the comments, you are wide open to [**SQL injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Comment: Ooh Wow I am an idiot for that. Haha. Need more coffee, or sleep would be better. Thanks. Not even a noob mistake, just idiotic.

Comment: :) Glad to help! I've been there. Please remember to select an answer!